# JDBC - MySQL timestamp - Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I was practicing JDBC. For database, I used MySql 8.0.18(MySql Workbench). But when i try to insert timestamp value, i got an exception.

JDBC code :

```
package jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class setupMySqlDatabase {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/employee?serverTimezone=UTC";
        String user = "JDBCUser";
        String password = "JDBCUser";
        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE species ("
                       + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                       + "name VARCHAR(255), "
                       + "num_acres DECIMAL)");
                       stmt.executeUpdate(
                       "CREATE TABLE animal ("
                       + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                       + "species_id integer, "
                       + "name VARCHAR(255), "
                       + "date_born TIMESTAMP)");

                       stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO species VALUES (1, 'African Elephant', 7.5)");
                       stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO species VALUES (2, 'Zebra', 1.2)");

                       stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO animal VALUES (1, 1, 'Elsa', '2001−05−06 00:02:15')");
                       stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO animal VALUES (2, 2, 'Zelda', '2002−08−15 09:12')");
                       stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO animal VALUES (3, 1, 'Ester', '2002−09−09 10:36')");
                       stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO animal VALUES (4, 1, 'Eddie', '2010−06−08 01:24')");
                       stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO animal VALUES (5, 2, 'Zoe', '2005−11−12 03:44')");
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When i run this code, i am getting below exception.

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '2001−05−06 00:02:15' for column 'date_born' at row 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:104)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1335)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2108)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1245)
    at jdbc.setupMySqlDatabase.main(setupMySqlDatabase.java:29)
```

I couldn't figure out why this error occured!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the dashes! Use simple dashes, not en-dash or em-dash (as you are using). You probably typed the code in the word processor earlier.

Change:

```
stmt.executeUpdate(
  "INSERT INTO animal VALUES (1, 1, 'Elsa', '2001−05−06 00:02:15')")
```

to:

```
stmt.executeUpdate(
  "INSERT INTO animal VALUES (1, 1, 'Elsa', '2001-05-06 00:02:15')")
```

Did you spot the difference? The first is using [Unicode Character − (U+2212)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2212), not simple dashes.

Comment: This is a typo question then, but I am upvoting for having good eyes +1.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you!! I am using Eclipse. Accidentally, I changed my default charset. It was cp1252. So, I changed it to US-ASCII. Now it works fine!!